# How is `pin_project` sound without `Unpin`

Tags: rust, reference, rust-pin

`pin_project` allows struct designers to get pinned references to struct fields out of a pinned reference to the whole struct. It further allows the designer to specify which fields need pinned references and which can simply get a regular reference:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct Demo<A, B> {
    #[pin]
    field_a: A,
    field_b: B,
}

impl<A, B> Demo {
    fn show_references(self: Pin<&mut Self>) {
        let this = self.project();
        let field_a: Pin<&mut A> = this.field_a;
        let field_b: &mut B = this.field_b;
    }
}
```

My question is how can the `field_b` part be sound without `B: Unpin`? The creation of a pinned reference "pins" the struct, mandating that the referenced struct must not move out of its location in memory. Wouldn't this property apply recursively, in the same way that mutability does? If `Demo` is pinned, doesn't that mean that `field_a` and `field_b` are implicitly pinned?

Comment: The type of `self` should really be `Pin<&mut Self>`- `Pin`'s type parameter is a pointer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [the documentation for pin projection](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/pin/index.html#projections-and-structural-pinning), the guarantee that `Pin` makes is not necessarily recursive.

The primary guarantee here is that "`Pin<P>` prevents certain values (pointed to by pointers wrapped in `Pin<P>`) from being moved." By design, this applies *specifically* to those values as a whole, with `Pin` itself making no claims about the fields of those values.

`Pin` could have been designed differently, but this particular approach is quite useful, because it lets each particular use case decide for itself whether it needs "structural" pinning (where a field must be pinned on its own) and "non-structural" pinning (where you can safely move or swap a field).

As an example, imagine a value of type `PinMe` that must be pinned, and put this value into a struct `Wrapper`. Pointers to such `Wrapper` values must be `Pin` pointers, to prevent moving the inner `PinMe`:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct Wrapper {
    #[pin]
    pinned: PinMe,
}

fn f(w: Pin<&mut Wrapper>) {
    // We cannot move the `Wrapper` that `w` points to, as that would move `w.pinned`.
    // All we can do is grab a pinned pointer to the `PinMe`:
    let inner: Pin<&mut PinMe> = w.project().pinned;
}
```

But if `Wrapper` has another field, completely unrelated to `PinMe`, there is no reason not to move or swap that field:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct Wrapper {
    #[pin]
    pinned: PinMe,
    counter: i32,
}

fn f(w: Pin<&mut Wrapper>) {
    let w = w.project();
    let inner: Pin<&mut PinMe> = w.pinned;
    let counter: &mut i32 = w.counter;

    // These sorts of operations do not affect the `PinMe`:
    *counter += 3;
    mem::replace(counter, 5);
}
```

The choice of structural vs non-structural pinning depends entirely on the invariants you need to uphold. If `field_b` needs to remain right next to `field_a`, then add `#[pin]` to it. But if that isn't something your `Demo` type needs, you can leave it out, which provides fewer guarantees but is still safe.

**Edit:** Further, this applies even if that extra field does not implement `Unpin`, so long as nothing has constructed a `Pin` pointing directly to it. For example:

```rust
#[pin_project]
struct Wrapper<T> {
    #[pin]
    pinned: PinMe,

    // We know nothing about this type except that it is `Sized`.
    // Thus, we cannot assume it implements `Unpin`.
    counter: T,
}

fn f<T>(w: Pin<&mut Wrapper<T>>, other: T) {
    let w = w.project();
    let inner: Pin<&mut PinMe> = w.pinned;
    let counter: &mut T = w.counter;

    // This is still okay:
    mem::replace(counter, other);
}
```

Comment: So, in this example, `counter` is an `Unpin` type. Does this reasoning apply as well to non-unpin types? Suppose for example that I was using this struct to "transport" a `Future` by move but haven't started polling it yet.

Comment: Ah, good question! Yes, this also applies to non-`Unpin` types- I've extended the answer to cover that.